# Why this method code doesn't take integer as it's parameter

Tags: c++

I am just trying to design a class to set and get the details of a student in C++.
So,to set the details of the student,i called `set_data(name,roll)` method.But this compilation error is coming.I have passed the same data type as actual arguments to the function as expected.I cant understand why error is coming.

```
G:\>g++ 5.cpp
5.cpp: In function 'int main()'
5.cpp:26:23: warning: deprecate
rite-strings]
 obj.set_data("asdf",15);
```

The code is ---

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>      
class pntr_obj
{
char *name;
int roll;
public:
void set_data(char *name,int roll)
{
this->name=name;
this->roll=roll;
}
void print()
{
cout<<"name is "<<this->name<<endl;

cout<<"roll is "<<this->roll<<endl;
}
};
int main()
{
pntr_obj obj;

obj.set_data("asdf",15);
obj.print();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: indent your code, `please`

Comment: have you learned what the *type* of a string literal (`"asdf"`) is yet?

Comment: Change *char to string.

Comment: "asdf" is taken as a string,correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Next time, please search for the error message / warning you get before posting a new question. This was trivial to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have passed the same data type as actual arguments to the function as expected.

No. `"asdf"` is [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) with type `const char[5]`, it might decay to `const char*`, but not `char *`.

> In C, string literals are of type `char[]`, and can be assigned directly to a (non-const) `char*`. C++03 allowed it as well (but deprecated it, as literals are const in C++). C++11 no longer allows such assignments without a cast.